# how to pass the parameter from one function to another function but with in the same class in php

Tags: php, class, oop

Here I want to pass the $user_id from editdata() function to the statusid() function but both are under the same class called User.

```
class User{

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","hep1");

    }
    public function execute_query($db,$query)
    {
        return mysqli_query($db,$query);

    }
public function editdata($user_id)
    {

        $query="SELECT * FROM employee_form WHERE id='$user_id'";
        $kal=$this->execute_query($this->db,$query);

        return $kal;
    }
public function statusid()
    {
        self::editdata($user_id);    //line 108

        $user_id=$user_id;   //line 110

        $query="SELECT status_name FROM employee_form WHERE id='$user_id'";
        $kal=$this->execute_query($this->db,$query);
    }
}
```

but whenever run this above code it shows error like this

> Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HT\Tasks\to-do-using-class\class.php on line 108
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: user_id in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\HT\Tasks\to-do-using-class\class.php on line 110

please help to solve this problem

Comment: How you get user id? without passing in statusid function. If you want to use directly then you have use setter and getter method for this.

Comment: How should the `statusid` method know which ID to pass? And why do you use a static call like `self::editdata()` to a non-static method? `$this->editdata()` looks much better

Comment: @ShashikantChauhan  how to use setter and getter method in above function please post your answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to write more or less object-oriented code, you should use object-oriented principles. Now your code looks like procedural code but wrapped in a class. You can start with the following structure:

```
class UserStorage
{
    private $db;

    // Do not create connection, but instead inject it
    public function __construct($db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    // Use interanl $db, do not pass new connection.
    public function query($query)
    {
        return mysqli_query($this->db, $query);
    }

    public function fetch($userId)
    {
        // Consider using prepared statements here.
        // Also consider using PDO and not mix procedural and OO style.
        return mysqli_fetch_assoc($this->query("SELECT * FROM employee_form WHERE id='$userId'"));
    }
}

$db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hep1");
$userStorage = new UserStorage($db);
$userId = 1;
$user = $userStorage->fetch($userId);
$status = $user['status_name'] ?? null;
```

Begin with reading about [SOLID principles](https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design).

Answer (score 1):

You can use getter and setter method following way. $user_id set by your form data or you can pass as static.

```
<?php
    class User
    {
        protected $user_id;
        public function __construct()
        {
            $this->db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "hep1");

        }
        public function setUserID($user_id)
        {
            return $this->user_id = $user_id;
        }
        public function getUserID()
        {
            return $this->user_id;
        }

        public function execute_query($db, $query)
        {
            return mysqli_query($db, $query);

        }
        public function editdata($user_id)
        {

            $query = "SELECT * FROM employee_form WHERE id='$user_id'";
            $kal   = $this->execute_query($this->db, $query);
            return $kal;
        }
        public function statusid()
        {
            $user_id =  self::getUserID();
            self::editdata($user_id); //line 108
            $query   = "SELECT status_name FROM employee_form WHERE id='$user_id'";
            $kal     = $this->execute_query($this->db, $query);
        }
    }

    // create a object 
    $user =  new User();
    // set user id here when you get
    $user_id = '1';
    $user->setUserID($user_id);
    $user->statusid();
```